# How to display question mark in Scintilla's autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, scintilla

I pass a list of words to Scintilla's **SCI_AUTOCSHOW** that looks like `"word? another-word! etc"` but it's displayed as `"word another-word etc"`, question mark and exclamation mark are gone. I've added them as valid word characters with **SCI_SETWORDCHARS** but that doesn't help. How can I force the autocomplete to show them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark is already used by Scintilla to indicate that a autocompletion list item has an associated image. So `word?2` would display the image registered with id `2`, and only `word` would be shown.

A different character to `?` can be set with [SCI_AUTOCSETTYPESEPARATOR](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_AUTOCSETTYPESEPARATOR).

I cannot reproduce similar behaviour with an exclamation mark. For me, when sending the `SCI_AUTOCSHOW` message with the string `"word? another-word! etc"`, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Exclamation mark was my own mistake and works as expected.